# Javascript: assign the popup tab as a variable

Tags: javascript, tabs

I have two domains on different hostings, domain A is the main website, domain B is the authorization server with simple frontend.
I have very strict security policy applied, which forces the users after 1 hour to re-authorize themselves. It's done by popup window in new tab, calling domain B from the frontend of the domain A.
I realized that the popup blocking policy and the fact, that not every browser behave the same, i found the only solution to bring the popup correctly (in the new tab) by this javascript call (when the timer reaches 60mins):

```
Object.assign(document.createElement('a'), { target: '_blank', href: 'https://domain_B/auth.php'}).click();
```

My problem is, that i am unable to check from the domain A, if the popup window is opened correctly and the user haven't closed it.
So i need to assign a variable to the new popup tab and check if it's still available, otherwise i need to re-open it from the domain A.

So i want to do something like this:

```
 if(popup_win && !popup_win.closed)
  { //do my auth stuff 
   }
```

the problem is, that i am unable to assign the new popup to `popup_win` javascript variable. I can do it by calling a single `window.open(url,"_blank")` but as i mentioned above, the result then depends on popup-blockers and browser version/type.

Any help/suggestion appreciated!

Comment: Does your domain B not have APIs to authenticate users? It seems like this problem would be much simpler if you could authenticate the user by just passing an API call from domain A to domain B.

Comment: I am using Google authenticator , where they need to input 6-digits to the domain B's simple popup. Then i am updating the session lifetime in the domain B's database, which is being called as an API request from domain A.